# PDF displaying in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs

I tried displaying the PDF file in laravel but this keeps on displaying. I tried all the suggested codes in the internet, but it will either not display or display like in the picture. I don't know what the problem is :(

my code
[image: my code]

output
[image: output]

Comment: Please add your code  and output as a text instead of an image. It will be easier to read and respond.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: `mb_convert_encoding` expects first parameter to be string. so instead of file name try reading the content and passing it as a first parameter

Answer (score 3):

I have used this library to generate PDF in laravel. Please look at doc.
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

You can also take help of my code. 
First install the library and configure as instructed in doc.
after that, In controller

```
// Put this in top
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;
```

create one function

```
public function DownloadPdf($id , $download = false){
      // instantiate and use the dompdf class
      $options = new Options();
      $options->set('enable_remote', true);
      $options->set('enable_css_float', true);
      $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
      $dompdf->loadHtmlFile(action('HomeController@PdfHTML',['id'=>$id]));

      // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
      $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

      // Render the HTML as PDF
      $dompdf->render();
      if($download == true){
        // Save PDF to server
        file_put_contents('uploads/pdf/document_'.$id.'.pdf', $dompdf->output());
      }else{
        // Output the generated PDF to Browser
        $dompdf->stream('document');
      }
    }
```

Now load the html file action

```
public function PdfHTML($id){

      return view('home.home_pdf');
    }
```

Now create `home.blade.pdf`

```
<h2>Hello world</h2>
```

Your PDF will be generated. Please let me know if you get any error

Answer (score 0):

The [Go trough this link](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/output.html)  state that the first argument of `Output()` is the file path, second is the saving mode - you need to set it to `'F'`.

```
 $upload_dir = public_path(); 
             $filename = $upload_dir.'/testing7.pdf'; 
              $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
              //$test = $mpdf->Image($pro_image, 0, 0, 50, 50);

              $html ='<h1> Project Heading </h1>';
              $mail = ' <p> Project Heading </p> ';
              
              $mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
              $mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
              $mpdf->WriteHTML($mail);

              $mpdf->Output($filename,'F'); 
              $mpdf->debug = true;
```

Example :

```
 $mpdf->Output($filename,'F');
```

Example #2

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');

// Saves file on the server as 'filename.pdf'
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE);
```